# How do I store a pointer to an object and reference it later to delete an item from an array?

Tags: swift

I am iterating through an array of objects and would like to delete the item if it matches a particular list of items. I cannot delete the item until after the the loop has completed iterating over the array. So I would like to store a temp pointer to the object and then delete it once it has finished iterating.

```
public func deleteItem(item: NSDictionary) {    
    for object in self.objects() {
        if object .isEqualToDictionary(item as! [String : String]) {
            //Store pointer to matched item
        }
    }
//Delete matched item 
}
```

How would I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use native types and the `filter` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple for loop indexing using `.enumerate()` should achieve what your after.

```
    public func deleteItem(item: NSDictionary) {    

        var deletionIndex = 0 //Initialize an index with wider scope.

        for object in self.objects().enumerate() { //Add .enumerate()

            //Add .element to get the object and .index for the index
            if object.element.isEqualToDictionary(item as! [String : String]) {

                //Store index to matched item instead of a pointer
                deletionIndex = object.index
            }
        }
       //Delete matched item 
       self.objects().removeAtIndex(deletionIndex)
    }
```

I feel like this actually should be easily attainable with a filter operation:

```
  public func deleteItem(item: NSDictionary) {    

    self.objects = self.objects.filter{ $0 != item }
}
```

This of course would delete all instances of an item instead of just the last known index

Comment: Much better solution that I came up with. Worked perfectly! Thanks!